# Allowing implementing interface only for specific classes

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface

Is it possible to permit only some specific classes to implement an iterface?
Let's say that I created interface `IMyInterface` and I want only classes which derive from `UserControl` to have an ability to implement my interface. Is this possible?

Comment: I'm still getting my head around interfaces vs abstract classes, but I think your question reveals something about the actual point of interfaces. If your interface is only compatible with certain classes, its probably too big (two shorter interfaces might be more reusable) or too small (the implementing class needs to have certain methods/properties to work... That's what interfaces are meant to ensure)

Answer (score 15):

You cannot, but you can achieve something similar by adding a Control property to your interface, and by-convention making all the implementations return `this`. Doesn't solve your problem, but makes the implementer think a bit whether or not the interface really belongs there. Also allows the user of the interface to retrieve the control in a type-safe manner without casting.

```
interface IMyInterface
{
    void Foo();
    UserControl Control { get; }
}


class MyControl : UserControl, IMyInterface
{
    public void Foo()
    {
        // TODO: Write code here
    }

    UserControl IMyInterface.Control
    {
        get { return this; }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

There is also another solution - making a generic method. The interface itself will not be restricted, but the method operating will be. For example, the following method requires that its parameter both inherits `UserControl` and implements `IMyInterface`:

```
void Bar<T>(T item)
  where T : UserControl, IMyInterface
{
    item.Width = 120;    // user control property
    item.Foo();          // IMyInterface method
}
```

Answer (score 12):

I realize this is an old post, but I had to solve exactly this problem.

Here is how you can do it:

```
class BaseClass { }

interface OnlyBaseClass<TSelf> where TSelf : BaseClass, OnlyBaseClass<TSelf>
{

}

class ChildClass : BaseClass, OnlyBaseClass<ChildClass> { }

class ImpostorClass : OnlyBaseClass<ImposterClass> { }

interface ImposterInterface : OnlyBaseClass<ImposterInterface > { }
```

Try to compile the above. You will notice that it doesn't compile (due to the two impostors, one a class, one an interface).

The constraint on **TSelf** can be understood as:

> *TSelf* must: Inherit from BaseClass *and* implement **OnlyBaseClass<*TSelf*>**

...which only a type inheriting from *BaseClass* and implementing *OnlyBaseClass* could do.

You could be clever, and do the following:

```
class AdvancedImpostorClass : OnlyBaseClass<ChildClass> {}
```

... which will compile. You could prevent these types of impostors from ever getting through into your code by using the same constraints in any methods that accept them as arguments though, like so:

```
public SomeMethod<TBaseAndInterface>(TBaseAndInterface value)
    where TBaseAndInterface: BaseClass, OnlyBaseClass<TBaseAndInterface>
{ }
```

This is all made possible through the power of [F-Bound Polymorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_quantification).

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you want something like this instead:

```
abstract class IMyInterface : UserControl { }
```

Of course `IMyInterface` is no longer an appropriate name, but any class that derives from `IMyInterface` would also derive from `UserControl`, which would satisfy your requirements.

Comment: This sounds like the most appropriate answer to the question as stated, but with one caveat: it would only work if you have the source code for all UserControl-derived classes that you wish to use. The abstract class must be "inserted" between UserControl and all UserControl-derived classes that you are using, which can only be done if you can change the source code for all the derived classes)

Comment: You would need multiple inheritance for classes to do that with multiple interfaces (so it's not possible in c#) :( . If you have only ONE interface to be set like that the solution is great

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible. If you can see the interface, you can implement it.

Comment: This is true of Interfaces. However, _if_ you own the source code for all the classes you wish to apply the "interface" to, you would be able to insert an abstract class into the derivation chain to achieve the required effect.

Comment: @Jason Williams: Even if one owns the source code for all of the intended implementations of an interface, that does not imply one will be able to define a common ancestor for all of the classes that would implement the interface.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no way of restricting the implementation of an interface to specific types.  Why would you need to?  Why does the consumer of an abstraction care about the concrete types that implement that contract?  What is your use case?

Comment: +1 and amen for `Why does the consumer of an abstraction care about the concrete types that implement that contract?`.

Comment: Usually for UserControl Interface works better and allows the designer in visual studio to behave properly for graphically editing the user control. Because of this sometimes we revert to using an interface for user controls when an abstract class inheriting UserControl would have been used otherwise

Comment: The interface might care. it may have some extension methods which assume the class it is implementing is of a particular type.

Answer (score 1):

The case you describe seems to fit an "abstract method in your parent class" (here userControl) , unless the interface already exists for other purposes.

Without default body, derivated classes will have to provide a behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from C# 8, interfaces' members may have access modifiers. Therefore, adding an `internal` member to the interface, without providing a default implementation, will prevent types outside that assembly from implementing it. This is based on a similiar solution with classes where you place an access modifier on the constructor to limit inheritance:

```
public interface IMyInterface
{
    internal void ExternalImplementationsDisabled();

    void MyMethod();
}
```

Implementing classes just need to provide an empty explicit implementation of this member. That member can also be hidden by replacing `internal` with `private protected`, making it inaccessible anywhere:

```
public interface IMyInterface
{
    private protected void ExternalImplementationsDisabled();

    void MyMethod();
}
```

Unfortunately, this solution doesn't limit implementation of `IMyInterface` to specific classes, though it does prevent types from outside the assembly from implementing it. To my knowledge, this is the only way to prevent types from implementing an interface.